# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [VB 2008]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I made a speech recogntion application but when I try to run it I got this erre

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim gram As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument
        Dim rule As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("command")
        Dim commandList As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf("Hello", "How are you", "I'm good to", "open google", "open facebook", "open twitter", "open youtube", "goto url", "run chrome", "run mozila", "run explorer", "open local d", "open local c", "run media player")
        rule.Add(commandList)
        gram.Rules.Add(rule)
        gram.Root = rule
        reco.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(gram)) >> HERE
        reco.RecognizeAsync()
    End Sub
```

Comment: care to share *where* it happens (what line)?

Comment: Well, `reco` comes out of nowhere, and since that is the form load event, it might not be initialized.  My guess is that if you hold the mouse over it, it will report `Nothing` making this a common ordinary dupe.